# Compilation Errors when code is modified in Eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse

I am using  Eclipse Indigo Service Release-2, jdk150_12 and weblogic server bea9.2MP3.Compilation errors are showing after modifications made to existing code even there is no wrong in code.Then I need to refresh , clean the project and restart server then only i am able to move forward.I have already checked build automatically under project menu.could you please tell me what are the possible solutions to resolve this issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reimport the whole project in Eclipse(sometimes the .settings folder and .project metadata hold wrong metainformation that conmetadatanfuses Eclipse).
Better check out the source in clean place and import it fresh.

Another thing you can do is check if your Eclipse has enough memory assigned.
It might be updating slowly because it does not have enough resources, especially if the project is very large.

So, go to `$YOUR_ECLIPSE_INSTALLATION_FOLDER` and update the values in `eclipse.ini`:
org.eclipse.platform

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  **256m**
--launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=**256m**
-Xms**40m**
-Xmx**512m**
```

E.g. double the highlighted values values.